# Determine If Numeric Value Is out of Range via If Statement

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement

I am trying to construct a dynamic `IF` statement in `bash` to determine if a number is within a pre-defined range or outside of it.

**some.file**

```
-11.6
```

**Bash Code:**

```
check=`cat some.file`

if [ ${check} -le "-7.0" ] && [ ${check} -ge "7.0" ];
then
echo "CAUTION: Value outside acceptable range"
else
echo "Value within acceptable range"
fi
```

Right now, I am getting returns of "Value within acceptable range" when clearly, `-11.6` is less than `-7.0` and therefore out of the range.

Comment: Also, it's recommended to use [`[[` over `[`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29).  If you're using just numeric comparisons, use `((` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$ cat f
2
$ awk '{if($1 >= -7.0 && $1 <= 7.0) {print "Value within acceptable range"} else {print "CAUTION: Value outside acceptable range"}}' f
Value within acceptable range

$ cat f
-11.6
$ awk '{if($1 >= -7.0 && $1 <= 7.0) {print "Value within acceptable range"} else {print "CAUTION: Value outside acceptable range"}}' f
CAUTION: Value outside acceptable range
```

**OR**

```
$ cat kk.sh
while IFS= read -r line
do
if [ $line -ge -7.0 ] && [ $line -le 7.0 ]; then
echo "Value within acceptable range"
else
echo "CAUTION: Value outside acceptable range"
fi
done < f
```

Processing ...

```
$ cat f
2
$ ./kk.sh
Value within acceptable range
```

---

```
$ cat f
-11.2
$ ./kk.sh
CAUTION: Value outside acceptable range
```